# inserting image in stringgrid cell

Tags: image, delphi, tstringgrid

i m using stringgrid in my application.The data is fetched from the database(backend mysql) and displayed in stringgrid.

[image]

I want to insert image in status cell of each row.
i.e.

```
      if status =online then -->image1
      else --->image2
```

anyone has any idea regarding how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to implement the OnDrawCell event.

Example :

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Longint;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  s: string;
  aCanvas: TCanvas;
begin
  if (ACol <> 1) or (ARow = 0) then
    Exit;
  s := (Sender as TStringGrid).Cells[ACol, ARow];

  // Draw ImageX.Picture.Bitmap in all Rows in Col 1
  aCanvas := (Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas;  // To avoid with statement
  // Clear current cell rect
  aCanvas.FillRect(Rect);
  // Draw the image in the cell
  if (s = 'online') then
    aCanvas.Draw(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Image1.Picture.Bitmap)
  else 
    aCanvas.Draw(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Image2.Picture.Bitmap);
end;
```

Comment: +1 but I find using **with** as a bad example, but that doesn't mean that the OP can't modify it (:

Comment: Change with to `aCanvas := (Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas` and write `aCanvas` instead of `Canvas` and get rid of the `with`.

Comment: @DorinDuminica and Warren, you are right. This is the only case I ever use the with statement, because I'm to lazy to define a helper var. Otherwise it should be banned for many reasons. Thanks.